# Is there an fsfreeze equivalent for Windows?

Tags: amazon-web-services, snapshot, aws-sdk

How does one freeze the Windows Server file system in order to safely make an AWS snapshot that has integrity?

On Linux, one can use fsfreeze. Is there an equivalent tool on Windows Server?